# jQuery: Replace \u002D in string from attr?

Tags: jquery, replace

From this div I want to extract the URL inside "ng-init"

```
<div ng-controller="CloudcastHeaderCtrl" ng-init="juno.replaceTracklist=true;juno.guid='DBFFF66E\u002D4111\u002D446B\u002D8471\u002D07DF1489F272';juno.chartUrl='http://www.junodownload.com/charts/mixcloud/RYCpodcast/ryc\u002Dpodcast\u002D108\u002Dpearl/254201612'">
```

But I can't seem to replace `\u002D` with `-`

```js
var ngInit = $('div[ng-controller="CloudcastHeaderCtrl"]').attr("ng-init"),
    url = ngInit.replace(/.+juno\.chartUrl='(.+)'/, "$1"),
    urlR = url.replace("\u002D", "-");

$("body").append( url + "<br />" );
$("body").append( urlR );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="CloudcastHeaderCtrl" ng-init="juno.replaceTracklist=true;juno.guid='DBFFF66E\u002D4111\u002D446B\u002D8471\u002D07DF1489F272';juno.chartUrl='http://www.junodownload.com/charts/mixcloud/RYCpodcast/ryc\u002Dpodcast\u002D108\u002Dpearl/254201612'">
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/7o7kL5pp/

Comment: `"\u002D"` is a single-character string (`\u` is a Unicode escape), not 6 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash is an escaping character. Since the target string contains a literal backslash, you need to escape it.

```js
var ngInit = $('div[ng-controller="CloudcastHeaderCtrl"]').attr("ng-init"),
    url = ngInit.replace(/.+juno\.chartUrl='(.+)'/, "$1"),
    urlR = url.replace("\\u002D", "-");

$("body").append( url + "<br />" );
$("body").append( urlR );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="CloudcastHeaderCtrl" ng-init="juno.replaceTracklist=true;juno.guid='DBFFF66E\u002D4111\u002D446B\u002D8471\u002D07DF1489F272';juno.chartUrl='http://www.junodownload.com/charts/mixcloud/RYCpodcast/ryc\u002Dpodcast\u002D108\u002Dpearl/254201612'">
```